# Check if string starts or ends with vbCrLf

Tags: vb.net, string

How can I check if a string starts (or ends) with `vbCrLf`?

I've tried with `substring` but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Dim s As String = ""
s &= vbCrLf & "Test"
If s.Substring(0, 1) = vbCrLf Then
    MsgBox("Yes")
End If
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

**StartsWith** - *checks the first part of a String.*

```
    Dim s As String = "vbCrLf bla bla bla"

    If s.StartsWith("vbCrLf") Then
        MsgBox("Yes")
    End If
```

**EndsWith** - *checks the last characters of a String.*

```
    Dim s As String = "bla bla bla vbCrLf"

    If s.EndsWith("vbCrLf") Then
        MsgBox("Yes")
    End If
```

Comment: Note that this uses a culture-dependent string comparison per default. For example in all cultures I know of, `"Strassenbahn".StartsWith("Straße")` will be `True`. There are other overloads of `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` where you can specify ___ordinal___ comparison, or specify culture-dependent comparison but use the `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Note the reason the OP's code doesn't work is that vbcrlf is _two_ characters. 
'If s.Substring(0, 2) = vbCrLf' works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Left (and Right) can be used in place of .StartsWith/.EndsWith if you're having issues with these.

```
Dim s As String
s = vbCrLf & "Test"
If Left(s, Len(vbCrLf)) = vbCrLf Then
    MsgBox("Yes")
End If
```

The simplest solution I could come up with for determining whether a string contains another string anywhere is to use the split function:

```
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim v As Variant
s = vbCrLf & "Test"
i = Split(s, vbCrLf)
For Each item In i
    j = j + 1
Next item
If j > 1 or vbCrLf = "" Then
    MsgBox("Yes")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking if there is a way to see if the string begins with a line brake. [Line Feed Return] (vbLf) or [Carriage Return] (vbCr). I use the Chr value to do that. Chr(13) is vbCr. Chr(10) is vbLf. You can use Asc to find out what the first Chr of a string is. Something like this;

```
Dim s As String = vbCr & "bla bla bla"

If Asc(s) = 13 Then
    MsgBox("s strats with a Carriage Return")
else If Asc(s) = 10 Then
    MsgBox("s strats with a Line Feed Return")
End If
```